# ASP.net GridView - Use If-Statement in HeaderText property of BoundField

Tags: asp.net, gridview, header, if-statement

Can I do something like this:

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="Field1" 
HeaderText='<% IF(Eval("Field2").ToString().SubString(3,4).Equals("Text3"),"Text1","Text2") %>'
SortExpression="Field1" />
```

With the goal of having the header of Field1 be Text1 when the 4th-7th characters of Field2 = Text3 and Text2 otherwise?

I tried it and it just put "'<% IF(Eval("Field2").ToString().SubString(3,4).Equals("Text3"),"Text1","Text2") %>'" as the actual header string!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Eval()` statement has meaning only within a data-binding context. As you'll find if you used data binding syntax (`<%# /*...*/ %>`), the header text does not provide a data-binding context. After all, there's only one header for zero-to-many rows.

You can set header text imperatively from the code-behind:

```
myGrid.Columns[columnIndex].HeaderText = //...
```

Comment: Oh ya. Good point. That makes absolutly no sence to have the headertext dependent on the Eval(). Thanks for poaring the cold water on my head and waking me up. +1